# Sed to replace specified line via powershell script

Tags: bash, powershell, sed

Invoking command to manage a virtual machine and trying to pass sed command but I'm unable to escape certain characters resulting in many syntax error messages.

Powershell script:
-ScriptText 'sed -i  `'61s#.*# < property name="jobExecutionIntervalInHours" value="24A" /> #`' filepath '

Tried that... please let me know

Much appreciated

Comment: How about using sed's `-f` parameter to specify a file that contains the commands instead of inventing complex escaping sequences?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit difficult without knowing more about the capabilities of your native `sed` command and `shell`. The following command should be portable to all POSIX compliant versions of `sed` and shells that support redirectors `>`.

```
sed '61s/.*/ < property name="jobExecutionIntervalInHours" value="24A" /g'  oldfile > newfile
```